# Is there a way to automatically exclude folders when adding a Google Doc to a Trello card?

Tags: google-drive, trello

Recently, when attaching a Google Doc to a Trello Card, I get the list of all folders and files in my Google Docs.  And it lists the Folders  at the top. There are so many folders, in fact (maybe 40 or 50) that I don't see any *files*

Previously it would show me a list of files, sorted with most recent first.
That meant that 95% of the time, the file I wanted to attach was in the first few documents.

If I manually type "-folder" everytime, then it shows no folders.

I'm wondering if there is a setting to automated this either in gDrive or in Trello